# Update data using Javascript ajax async failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, google-chrome-extension, get

I am using **HTML**, **javascript** and **Nodejs** code to develop chrome extension.
On page load, I am calling the function `getBalance()` to get data and bind it to the HTML span. Following is my code:

```
function getBalance() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx/getAccount?address=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', true);
    request.onload = function () {
      var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
      if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
        var bal = data.Balance;
        var etherprice = bal / 1000000000000000000;
        document.getElementById("accbal").innerHTML = etherprice;
      } else {
        console.log('error');
      }
    }
    request.send(null);
}

window.addEventListener('load', function load(event){
    getBalance();
});

function sendTransactionBroadcast(result){ 
    var doAjax = function() { 
    $.ajax({ 
    type : "POST", 
    url : "http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx/broadcast",   
    data: JSON.stringify(result), 
    contentType: 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8', 
    success:function(json){ 
      console.log(json);
      getBalance();
    }, 
    error: function() { 
    alert("Error"); 
    } 
    }); 
    } 
    doAjax(); 
    }
```

`sendTransactionBroadcast()` function is called on button click, this function is having **ajax async POST call**. After its execution complete, On success, I want updated data from `getBalance()` function and bind it to the span. So, I am calling it again on ajax success. Problem is, if I set debugger and debug the code line by line, I get the updated data in span innerHTML. Everything goes fine. But, if I close debugger, and click the button the span innerHTML is not getting changed on UI. I am not getting the reason why? Also sometimes it changed sometimes not. 
Is this ajax async response issue or something else? How to solve this?

*`manifest.json`*

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "C Wallet",
  "description": "The C Wallet in your browser",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "Image/CI_logo-01.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "icons": { "16": "Image/CI_logo-01.png",
    "48": "Image/CI_logo-01.png",
   "128": "Image/CI_logo-01.png" 
  },
  "permissions": [
   "activeTab"
   ]
}
```

Comment: At first glance seems like your `getBalance` function is caching some values: Try `request.open('GET', 'http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx/getAccount?address=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&someRandomValue=' + Date.now() , true);` This should force the browser to pull data from the server instead of the browser cache

Comment: I tried this, now I get to know that at button's first click it is working fine. On the second click, it does not get updated.

Comment: Your code seems to be working as expected! I tried it with a fake API, it's working fine. It also updates the price on subsequent clicks

Comment: @Saroj you used it on Chrome extension?

Comment: Nope. Just trying it out with simple html and js.

Comment: Okay but on simple HTML and js, it will work.

Comment: Extensions have different parts with different permissions, restrictions, and capabilities. You need to provide more info like manifest.json and describe where exactly the posted code fragment runs.

Comment: @wOxxOm please check manifest fie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the problem. As I was using **HTML** `button type="submit"` which was the reason that the page was getting load and the data was not getting changed according to what I was setting. It was getting reset. To avoid page load I used `button type="button"` and all problems got solved.